# Automate downloading of certain csv files from a website

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, wget

I am trying to automate downloading of certain csv files from a website.

This is how I manually do it:

1. I log in to the website.
2. Click on the button `export as csv`.
3. The file gets downloaded.

The problem is the button does not have any link to it so I was not able to automate it using `wget` or `requests`.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

May be you can try `pywinauto`
https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Using `pywinauto` you can automate opening the link on your browser and downloading the csv file. Obviously the downside is that it will open browser and click the button, so it is not running in the background.

Option 2:

Check what query is posted when you click the button and replicate the same.

Comment: Thankyou for the response.Can you brief me on the second option?

Comment: Can you post the relevant part of the html code (corresponding to the button)

Answer (score 0):

You can use selenium in python. There is an option to click using "link text" or "partial link text". It is quite easy and efficient.

`driver.findElement(By.linkText("click here")).click()`

It kind of looks like this.